# Elixir: Installing Elixir on Ubuntu kills running Couch DB instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, couchdb, elixir

Recently tried to install Elixir on Ubuntu 12.0.4 with the instructions found here (basically using `apt-get install elixir`) - http://elixir-lang.org/install.html

Once the installation had completed, I found that I could not reach the CouchDB instance running on - http://localhost:5984.

So I tried to remove and reinstall Couch itself. After doing so, I still couldn't reach CouchDB on localhost.

Only after removing CouchDB, Erlang and Elixir (with `apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin erlang-base erlang-base-hipe erlang-solutions`) was I able to reinstall CouchDB, with a simple `apt-get install couchdb` command.

I assume the Elixir installation upgrades Erlang/OTP to v18.1...
Is this upgrade causing the issue? 
And if so, how can I work around it to use both CouchDB and Elixir on the same machine?

Comment: Did you try the advice here http://blog.danielberkompas.com/elixir/2015/08/28/how-to-run-elixir-cloud9-ide.html  about doing sudo touch /etc/init.d/couchdb    ?

Comment: Didn't work, as it would suggest that I should install Elixir first and then Couch. I tried that, and ran into the same state found above.

Comment: Did you try installing from source?

Comment: Is `epmd` being terminated during the upgrade process? Something like that could cause trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of things, the standard Ubuntu Couch installation package found here - https://launchpad.net/~couchdb/+archive/ubuntu/stable - installs CouchDB ver 1.6.1, with Erlang/OTP R14 as a dependency.

When you install Elixir from the package found on the official website, it installs Erlang/OTP R18 as a dependency, overwriting any previously installed version.

Three problems with that.

- The CouchDB installation isn't automatically reconfigured to use the latest
  Erlang VM available on your machine.
- Installing Couch from the apt get package breaks down if it finds an 'incompatible' Erlang/OTP VM already installed.
- When compiling from the source found here -
  https://github.com/apache/couchdb - the build process will die if it
  finds an Erlang/OTP VM earlier than R12, or later than R17!...
  Apparently, Couch was patched to use Erlang R18, but it didn't appear
  to work when I tried building the project from tag 1.6.1 in the github
  repo.

Sigh.

So in the end, I settled on using this - https://github.com/jhs/build-couchdb - 
Which, I think, installs a localised version of the Erlang VM in the build folder. That's not ideal...

Once I have more information, I'll update this answer.

Cheers for the help.

EDIT - I think it uses the same version of Erlang/OTP already installed, if available.

Comment: Same problem here; it's sad to see CouchDB is not catching up - and I somehow feel down about it more & more, despite the fact I like it very much.

Comment: CouchDB dev here: Alternatively, you can install CouchDB [1.x.x](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/tree/1.x.x) or [1.6.x](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/tree/1.6.x) from source after installing Elixir with Erlang R18. Note that you cannot use the 1.6.1 release tarball, but have to build from a git checkout. — both branches are safe to build from source and run in production.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried first (see the answer), but at the time of writing, it choked on the R18 instance of Erlang/OTP I had running on my linux box.